# OData v4.0 aggregate queries (aggregate query syntax)

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, aggregation

For example,
I have an object model:

```
Product
{ 
  int ProductId,
  string Name,
  List<Sale> Sales
}
```

- I want to use the aggregate queries to get total Amount of Sales:

**GET: Product?$apply=groupby(Name, aggregate(Sales(Amount with sum as Total)))** *(follow as oasis-open standard)*

--> Got error: *UriQueryExpressionParser_CloseParenOrCommaExpected=" ')' or ',' expected at position {0} in '{1}'.* ". position at Amount.

- I change the query to:

**GET: Product?$apply=groupby(Name, aggregate(Sales/Amount with sum as Total))**

--> Work successfully!.

**My question**:

--> Had current version OData Core supported the aggregate query syntax as my example "**aggregate(Sales(Amount with sum as Total))**" or NOT?

Please give me your advice.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tracked at https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/463

The query

```
Product?$apply=groupby(Name, aggregate(Sales/Amount with sum as Total))
```

should throw exception as well, it's not supported yet.

Answer (score -5):

A solution is to use the `QueryByCube` function provided by the [AdaptiveLINQ component](https://www.adaptivelinq.com).
Disclaimer: I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developer

Comment: I'm downvoting this shameless plug... maybe give a code example of how you would solve the question being posted using the library?