# OData aggregate queries

Tags: c#, api, odata

I am working with API 2 and OData 5.6 
every thing is ok .. but I don't know how to get aggregates (sum,count max ...)
I had installed this [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.ODataQueryMapper) 
then I've used

```
$apply=aggregate(Salary with sum as Total)
```

and tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427634/odata-aggregate-query-with-count)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009270/odata-v4-0-aggregate-queries-aggregate-query-syntax) also
but it always gives me an error

> (The query parameter '$apply' is not supported.)

so plz help to do it